# Create UIToolbar in UIViewController without navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I have create a nib that is a UIViewController and have drag a UIToolbar to my interface using the nib.  I have make the necessary link of the toolbar in nib to the IBOutlet UIToolbar class variable. When I run the app, the toolbar did not appear.  Am I missing out something? I have also create the @property and @syntesize for the class variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever add the toolbar to your view controller's view, either in your nib or in code after loading the nib?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on the iPad.

By default the toolbar added with the interface builder is positioned at the bottom of the view (and in my case it didn't appear at all).

When I changed the toolbar position (using the Size/Autosizing inspector) to stick at the top, where I wanted it, the toolbar appeared.